# Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)^m} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

> Problem: Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)^m} $

Approach: I want to use contour integration to evaluate the desired integral. I tend to choose the close contour is the circle centered at the origin and the radius is $R$. When I solve the roots for $z^4+2az^2+1=0$, I can find the solution, but I cannot determine whether they are in the close contour or not. So I thought this method may fail.

Comment: How does a circle contribute to solving the integral in question?

Comment: @Accelerator Sorry, It should be a Semi circle.

Comment: I see. In that case, for sufficiently large $R$, the integral $\int_{-R}^R f(x)dx$ (where $f(x)$ is the integrand in question) doesn't converge when $a \leq -1$, so that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Accelerator cool, i never noticed that

Comment: wait, I think the integrand is bounded by $1/x^4$ and $\int 1/x^4$ converges.

Comment: If your goal is to find out what the integral equals, it doesn't matter what an upper bound for the integral is.